# Validating multiple user generated tags in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, validation

On my website, I allow users to upload images. Alongside these images, users can also add tags to the images.

Fiddle demo found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/cn9nqfj3/4/

I have two problems with this, however.

First, how could I even pass this through as with the rest of the request?

For example, in my controller's validation, I have:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|max:40|min:2|string',
    'mature' => 'required',
    'categorie' => 'required',
    'description' => 'string|max:2000',
    'fileUpload' => 'required|image',
    'tag' => 'max:20|alpha_num',
]);
```

but how would the tags work?

When adding tags, the markup is generated like so:

```
<span class="tag"><span class="close">×</span>#tag1</span>
<span class="tag"><span class="close">×</span>#tag2</span>
```

so I'm not sure how I would even pass this through to validation as it's not a regular form element.

The second problem is how the validation would even handle multiple tags.

Would I need something like a foreach construct to check if I don't, say,  exceed the tag amount limit, and then validate them all one by one for things like alphanumeric and whatnot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can use select2 plugin which is discussed in this laracast series episode...
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/24

Comment: This doesn't answer my question directly, but I ended up going through with your answer, so I guess I'll accept yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would need the input to come in as an array of inputs.

IE `<input type="text" name="tag[]">`

To get this, you'll have to look at ways to get the information out of your javascript tag plugin.  Most tag plugins have a method for this or will generate input fields for you.

In Laravel you can validate arrays, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#validating-arrays

Your last line would be `'tag.*' => 'max:20|alpha_num',`

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped quite a bit, despite switching to the select2 plugin .